# k-nearest neighbor (KNN) algorithm implemented in S&P 500 index with python

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I'd like to implement K-nearest neighbor algorithm to S&P 500 index to predict future price and develop quantitative algorithm trading model with python via scikit-learn library.
 Although I have basic understanding of kNN algorithm, I am a complete novice of machine learning coding with python, so I'd pleased if anybody can help me.

Here goes my simulation logic

1. Asset : S&P 500 index monthly price (investable with ETF)
2. Logic

   - Predict the price direction of next month (up or down) based on kNN algorithm every end of month ----> predicted up: buy S&P 500 index, down: hold cash (hypothetical index of 3% annual return)
   - Training data set : recent rolling 12 monthly data (training data set is constantly changed as time goes by, like in the case of moving average)
   - Independent variable : recent 3, 6, 9, 12 moth return, recent 12 month rolling standard deviation of monthly return
   - Dependent variable : next month return expressed as positive or negative

Here's my code. I could code basic dataset, but have no idea of coding main algorithm and simulation logic. Anybody can complete this code?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def price(stock, start):
    price = web.DataReader(name=stock, data_source='yahoo', start=start)['Adj Close']
    return price.div(price.iat[0]).resample('M').last().to_frame('price')

a = price('SPY','2000-01-01')
a['cash'] = [(1.03**(1/12))**x for x in range(len(a.index))]
a['R3'] = a.price/a.price.shift(3)
a['R6'] = a.price/a.price.shift(6)
a['R9'] = a.price/a.price.shift(9)    
a['R12'] = a.price/a.price.shift(12)    
a['rollingstd'] = a.price.pct_change().rolling(12).std()
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it. While this is another version of strategy using fractal momentum score, it may be helpful

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from sklearn import neighbors, svm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

def price(stock, start):
    price = web.DataReader(name=stock, data_source='yahoo', start=start)['Adj Close']
    return price.div(price.iat[0]).resample('M').last().to_frame('price')

def fractal(a, p):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for count in range(1,p+1):
        a['direction'] = np.where(a['price'].diff(count)>0,1,0)
        a['abs'] = a['price'].diff(count).abs()
        a['volatility'] = a.price.diff().abs().rolling(count).sum()
        a['fractal'] = a['abs']/a['volatility']*a['direction']
        df = pd.concat([df, a['fractal']], axis=1)
    return df

def meanfractal(a, l=12):
    a['meanfractal']= pd.DataFrame(fractal(a, l)).sum(1,skipna=False)/l

a = price('^KS11','2000-01-01')
a['cash'] = [(1.03**(1/12))**x for x in range(len(a.index))]
a['meanfractal']= pd.DataFrame(fractal(a, 12)).sum(1,skipna=False)/12   
a['rollingstd'] = a.price.pct_change().shift(1).rolling(12).std()
a['result'] = np.where(a.price > a.price.shift(1), 1,0)     
a = a.dropna()

print(a)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
clf1 = svm.SVC()
clf3 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)

a['predicted']= pd.Series()
for i in range(12,len(a.index)):
    x  =  a.iloc[i-12:i,6:8]    
    y  =  a['result'][i-12:i] 
    clf3.fit(x, y)
    a['predicted'][i]= clf3.predict(x)[-1] 

a = a.dropna()
a.price = a.price.div(a.price.ix[0])
print(a)
accuracy=clf3.score(a.iloc[:,6:8],a['result'])

a['결과'] = np.where(a.predicted.shift(1)==1,a.price/a.price.shift(1),1).cumprod()
a['result'] = np.where(a.predicted.shift(1)==1,(a.price/a.price.shift(1)+1.0026)/2,1.0026).cumprod()
a['동일비중'] = ((a.price/a.price.shift(1)+1.0026)/2).cumprod()
a[['result','price','결과']].plot()
plt.show()
print ("Predicted model accuracy: "+ str(accuracy))
```